# iOS Table view glitch while scrolling

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, scroll

Hy guys, i have a problem, have a tableview with 4 images on each cell, i need to know which image was clicked, so i put images on button

All works good, but it sticks while scrolling, not crash, just stuck to think a second, then scroll again. Can someone help ? 
here is the code:

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

UIButton *b1, *b2, *b3, *b4;
UIImageView *lBut1,*lBut2,*lBut3,*lBut4;
if (cell == nil)        
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

b1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
b1.frame = CGRectMake(y, y, x, x);
UIImage* img = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row*4]];
[b1 setBackgroundImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal];
b1.tag = indexPath.row*4+1;
[b1 addTarget:self action:@selector(reportChoose:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
lBut1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Default.png"]];
lBut1.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, x, x);
[lBut1 setAlpha:0.5];
[b1 addSubview:lBut1];
[lBut1 release];
[cell addSubview:b1];

if (indexPath.row * 4 + 1 < [dataArray count]) {
    b2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    b2.frame = CGRectMake(2*y+x, y, x, x);
    UIImage* img = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row*4 + 1]];
    [b2 setBackgroundImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    b2.tag = indexPath.row*4+2;
    [b2 addTarget:self action:@selector(reportChoose:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    lBut2 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Default.png"]];
    lBut2.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, x, x);
    [lBut2 setAlpha:0.5];
    [b2 addSubview:lBut2];
    [lBut2 release];
    [cell addSubview:b2];
}

if (indexPath.row * 4 + 2 < [dataArray count]) {
    b3 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    b3.frame = CGRectMake(3*y+2*x, y, x, x);
    UIImage* img = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row*4 + 2]];
    [b3 setBackgroundImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    b3.tag = indexPath.row*4+3;
    [b3 addTarget:self action:@selector(reportChoose:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    lBut3 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Defaulte.png"]];
    lBut3.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, x, x);
    [lBut3 setAlpha:0.5];
    [b3 addSubview:lBut3];
    [lBut3 release];
    [cell addSubview:b3];
}
if (indexPath.row * 4 + 3 < [dataArray count]) {
    b4 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    b4.frame = CGRectMake(4*y+3*x, y, x, x);
    UIImage* img =[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row*4 + 3]];
    [b4 setBackgroundImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    b4.tag = indexPath.row*4+4;
    [b4 addTarget:self action:@selector(reportChoose:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    lBut4 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Defaulte.png"]];
    lBut4.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, x, x);
    [lBut4 setAlpha:0.5];
    [b4 addSubview:lBut4];
    [lBut4 release];
    [cell addSubview:b4];
}

return cell;
```

}

Comment: THis table contains 4 images per row and i need to know which image was clicked, that's why i use different tag for each button.

Answer (score 2):

cells should be reused.
You add more and more buttons when the cells are scrolled. Allocations and adding views as subview takes time.
When you scroll around long enough you'll run out of memory.

Use a pattern like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UIButton *button;
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        button.tag = 1001;
        // configure button properties that never change between rows
        button.frame = ...

        [cell.contentView addSubview:button];
    }
    UIImage *myImage = ...

    button = (UIButton *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1001];
    // configure properties that are different for each row
    [button setBackgroundImage:myImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    return cell;
}
```

Add subviews only in `if (cell == nil)`. Configure them outside of that condition.

Or create a UITableViewCell subclass that holds your buttons.

Comment: But if i want to find which button was clicked ?

Answer (score 0):

Best method is to create a CUstom TableViewCell to make your job easier.

You can write the selectors in the custom tableviewcell class.

http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/custom-uitableviewcell/

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common problem. Two points that i should tell :

1) Reuse tableView cells. (Quite common approach by UITableView)
2) Cache as much data as possible. Caching though increases memory footprint, but it will also improve scrolling. Though the level of caching has to be determined through proper testing (use instruments for this).